# Where to get a reference image for any unicode code point?

Tags: unicode

I am looking for an online service (or collection of images) that can return an image for any unicode code point.

Unicode.org does not have an image for each one, consider for example
http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=31cf

**EDIT:**  I need to use these images programmatically, so the code chart PDFs provided at unicode.org are not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images in the PDF are copyrighted, so there are legal issues around extracting them. (I am not a lawyer.) I suspect that those legal issues prevent a simple solution from being provided, unless someone wants to go to the trouble of drawing all of those images. It might happen, but seems unlikely.

Your best bet is to download a selection of fonts that collectively cover the entire range of characters, and display the characters using those fonts. There are two difficulties with this approach: combining characters and invisible characters.

The combining characters can easily be detected from the Unicode database, and you can supply a base character (such as NBSP) to use for displaying them. (There is a special code point intended for this purpose, but I can't find it at the moment.)

Invisible characters could be displayed with a dotted square box containing the abbreviation for the character. Those you may have to locate manually and construct the necessary abbreviations. I am not aware of any shortcuts for that.